# How to explode row with different ids?

Tags: mysql, explode

I need a help. I have qurum table

```
qurum table             data table
qurum_id|qurum            id|qurum1
       1|one               1|3
       2|two               2|2
       3|three             3|1
       4|four              4|7
       5|five              5|5,6
       6|six               6|4
       7|seven             7|5
where qurum_id = data.qurum1
```

The result must be

```
qurum_id|qurum|qurum1
       1|one  |3
       2|two  |2
       3|three|1
       4|four |7
       5|five |5
     **6|six  |6
       6|six  |4**
       7|seven|5
```

This is query

```
`SELECT qurum_id, qurum,qurum1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(aa.input_date, '%m') BETWEEN 01 AND 06
           THEN 1 END) AS I,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(aa.input_date, '%m') BETWEEN 07 AND 12
           THEN 1 END) AS II
FROM qurum AS qur
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, qurum1,input_date FROM DATA ) AS aa
            ON qur.qurum_id = aa.qurum1
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(aa.input_date, '%Y') = $year
GROUP BY qurum_id
ORDER BY qurum_id`
```

The result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azSwL.png)

There is sixth row with qurum1 = 6|7 in the table, but I need to explode 6|7 because qurum_id 6 and qurum_id 7 has different qurum. Pic will [show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eswPX.jpg) the best what I want to say

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(qurum1, ' ', 1) AS first_part,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(qurum1, ' ', -1) as second_part FROM qurum;
```

Comment: `      SELECT qurum_id, qurum,qurum1,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(aa.input_date, '%m') BETWEEN 01 AND 06
   THEN 1 END) AS I,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(aa.input_date, '%m') BETWEEN 07 AND 12
   THEN 1 END) AS II,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(qurum1, '|', 1) AS first_part,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(qurum1, '|', -1) as second_part
FROM qurum AS qur
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, qurum1,input_date FROM DATA ) AS aa
   ON qur.qurum_id = aa.qurum1
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(aa.input_date, '%Y') = 2017
GROUP BY qurum_id
ORDER BY qurum_id`  Like this?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141896/mysql-explode

Comment: I added one more digit to qurum1 (now it is 1|6|7) and the row disapperared

Comment: I beg you please help